# Move all text between two "\t" in Notepad++

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I have more than a million lines of text in this format:

```
AAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCC
```

Separated by `\t`

I want to have it in a format

```
AAAA_CCCC BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how to do it using regular expressions in Notepad++

Comment: It seems you could try `\t(.+)\t(.+)` and replace with `_\2 \1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^(\S+)\t(\S+)\t(\S+)$
Replace: $1_$3 $2
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kkbWtl/1).

Comment: This worked beautifully and the link you provided gives a good explanation which I really needed to make sense of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the separator is a tab, you can use

```
^[^\r\n\t]+\K\t([^\r\n\t]+)\t([^\r\n\t]+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\r\n\t]+` Match 1+ chars other than a tab or newline
- `\K\t` Forget what is matches so far using `\K` and match a tab
- `([^\r\n\t]+)` Capture **group 1**, match any 1+ chars other than a newline or tab
- `\t` Match a tab
- `([^\r\n\t])` Capture **group 2**, match 1 char other than a newline or tab
- `$` end of string

In the replacement use the 2 capture groups with an underscore in between.

```
_$2 $1
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3vdETM/1).

The result of the replacement:

```
AAAA_CCCC   BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: Working fine from my side